# Select Text From multiple JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

In the same `JPanel` , i have two `JEditorPane`, how i can select text from the two `JEditorPane` at the same time

```
JPanel panel=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JEditorPane jeditorpane1=new JEditorPane();
// Set content of jeditorpane1
JEditorPane jeditorpane2=new JEditorPane();
// Set content of jeditorpane2
panel.add(jeditorpane1,BorderLayout.WEST);
panel.add(jeditorpane2,BorderLayout.EAST);
```

I use mouse to select text from jeditorpane !

Answer (score 1):

```
jeditorpane1.selectAll();
jeditorpane2.selectAll();
```

But when `JEditorPane` is not focused selection is invisible

to make it visible use

```
((DefaultCaret)jeditorpane1.getCaret()).setSelectionVisible(true);
```

Comment: it doesn't work !

My question is , when i use mouse in order to select text from one jeditorpane it's work fine , but i want select text from 2 jeditorpane at the same time by mouse !

Comment: I don't understand how it should work. Please describe more... also add why do you need the feature?

Comment: in my panel , i have 2 jeditorpane , when i run the application , i use mouse to select text from eatch jeditorpane. but i can't select text from 2 jeditorpane using mouse

Comment: Store where mouse was pressed and where released. Transform the coordinates to JEditorPane's. Use viewToModel() to obtain caret positions for selection start and end. select text according to your positions